# Passing variables in DolphinDB metaprogramming

Tags: metaprogramming, dolphindb

Is it feasible to replace a specified value with a variable in metaprogramming? For example, I intend to replace `where Date = 2015.01.15` with `where Date = $(date)`, in which “date“ is a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the following two methods:

1.Concatenate related strings;

2.Use the `sql` function as follows:

```
n=100;
t=table(2020.01.01 + 0..(n-1) as timestamp, rand(`IBM`MS`APPL`AMZN,n) as symbol, rand(10.0, n) as value)
d = 2020.01.01
sql(sqlCol("*"), t, <timestamp=d>).eval()
```

For details, see [sql — DolphinDB 2.0 documentation](https://docs.dolphindb.cn/en/help200/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/s/sql.html?highlight=sql).